# Error when calling a sub from another sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get location of cells with a specific name from two excel files, and write them into a third excel file. The sub worked okay, when used in isolation. However, as soon as I plug it in another sub I get the following error: "object variable or with block variable not set"

It happens at line wbfrom = wb_from.

```
'Sub Copy_cells()


Sub Copy_cells(wb_from As Workbook, wb_to As Workbook)

    'Dim wb_macro As Workbook: Set wb_macro = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    'Dim sFilePath As String
    'Dim NewTemplate
    'NewTemplate = Application.GetOpenFilename

    'Dim wb_from As Workbook
    'Set wb_from = Workbooks.Open(NewTemplate)
    
    Dim wbfrom As Workbook
    Dim wbmacro As Workbook
    Dim wbto As Workbook
    
    wbfrom = wb_from
    wbmacro = ThisWorkbook
    wbto = wb_to
    
    wbmacro.Sheets("Engine").Activate
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J2:J100")
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim cel_name As String
    Dim ra_from As Range
    Dim ra_to As Range

    For Each cel In rng 'look at first 100 different rows
        If Not cel.Value = "" Then
            cel_name = cel.Value

            Set ra_from = wbfrom.Sheets("Core").Cells.Find(What:=cel_name, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            wbmacro.Sheets("Engine").Activate
            wbmacro.Sheets("Engine").Range(cel.Address).Offset(0, 3) = ra_from.Address
            
            Set ra_from = wbto.Sheets("Core").Cells.Find(What:=cel_name, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            wbmacro.Sheets("Engine").Activate
            wbmacro.Sheets("Engine").Range(cel.Address).Offset(0, 4) = ra_from.Address
        


        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see the point of duplicating the variables but you need to use `Set` since they are objects: `Set wbfrom = ...`

Comment: So I can just directly use wb_from etc, without first dim?

Comment: Yes, you can. That's kind of the point. :)